# Mobile navigation not clickable when browser search bar is expanded

Tags: html, css, browser, navigationbar, hamburger-menu

**Hi everyone.**

I'm currently working on a website for my company, and right now I'm facing a problem with the navigation menu, specifically on mobile devices, or should I say, mobile browsers(most of them).

The **hamburger icon** is clickable when the browser's search bar is expanded, but becomes irresponsive when scrolling down(as the search bar becomes shrank).

It does work however on **Chrome** browser, as it doesn't shrink the search bar, but any other browser that I have tried refuses to do so. (**Safari, Firefox, Samsung Browser**, etc.)

I'm not sure how can that affects the hamburger menu, as it works perfectly on **Chrome/Safari** with Inspect element on mobile modes.

**[Here](https://globalconstructii.md)** is my website (*still work in progress*)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Also please read: [can I just link to my Website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)!

Comment: can you share ```Code``` what you have done?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

From my current testing, I suspect your navigation pop up menu is slightly too big to pop up in Mozila Firefox default mobile size. If I flip the mobile size to landscape, you will be able to see the responsive of your navigation menu.

I will suggest you to try make the navigation menu to be smaller in width in your css code which will solve your issue with minimal editing.

Again just suggesting only this may not be the best solution but I personally feel that it works.

Regards,
JJSIMCYBERTECH.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <h1>(Website Name)</h1>
            <input type="search" class="searchbox">
            <a href="#"><button class="btn">(Element)</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn">(Element)</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn">(Element)</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button class="btn">(Element)</button></a>
        </div>
        
        <style>
            .nav{
                background-color: lightgreen;  
                border: 2px solid white;
                /* choose your color */
                color: red;
            }
                
            .searchbox{
            
                background-color: gray;
                width: 300px;
                height: 35px;
                color: white;
            }
            
            .btn{
                border: none;
                background-color: #184a26;
            }
            
            .btn:hover{
                padding: 5px;
            }
            
        </style>
        
    </body>
</html>
```